# How to display ChoiceField in django with html file?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

I am new to django and I am trying to get ChoiceField working for user entry.
I have tried two iterations of html but neither display any form of drop down.

see my code below for models, forms , html

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):

    CATEGORIES=(
        ('COM', 'Combat'),
        ('CRA', 'Crafting'),
        ('WAR', 'Warfare'),
    )

    post= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    post2= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CATEGORIES)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

forms.py

class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField()
    post2 = forms.CharField()

    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Post.CATEGORIES)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post','post2','category',)

html


    <form method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}} or {{form}}


        <input type="submit" value="Submit">


    </form>
```

views.py

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'fitness/name.html'

```
def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

def post(self, request):

    form = HomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        form = HomeForm()
        return redirect('home:home')

    args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: Where is the view? And what *is* displayed?

Comment: just added to question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    post = forms.CharField()
    post2 = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('post','post2','category',)
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.Select(choices=Post.CATEGORIES,attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, however nothing is still displayed , just Post 1 and Post 2 entry fields . Category then appears as a string without any drop down. Then just the submit button.

Comment: Hey, check if this works, the problem is you are using a ModelForm which works a little differently from normal Form

Comment: Thanks for your help however It's still displaying the same thing. I wondered origionally whether it was a html problem?

Comment: Pinpointing the issue is getting difficult, although, I would recommend you follow best practices of Django, a lot of places you have deviated from them. When this happens small things can end up causing time-killing issues. http://www.marinamele.com/django and two scoops of Django are two of the best resources for it.

Comment: I really think that the issue here is how you are handling the ModelForm, try to redo the entire thing using class based views, read up on how ModelForm view should be written, the biggest advantage of using a ModelForm  is writting class based views.

Comment: I have written a class based view by the way. It just did not format properly in pasting. Also I have copied numerous examples of trying to do choicefield with model forms and nothing is ever showing the drop down.